# How to do a Live Migration of a vanilla Cassandra cluster to a Datastax Enterprise Cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

We currently have a Cassandra cluster up and running in a production environment using Cassandra 3.3.0. We want to switch this to a DSE cluster without having any down time.

We have a tool for migrating the schema already, but what is the best way to migrate the data from our Cassandra cluster to the new Datastax cluster without any sort of down time?

If you were switching clusters with regular Cassandra, you could merely join Nodes from the new cluster to the currently running cluster, then shutdown the old nodes after all of the new nodes have been added. This is nice because it requires no additional code to migrate the data, is there any solution similar to this available for DSE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would install DSE to match your version of Cassandra around the cluster. However I noticed you're listing Cassandra 3.3.0, is that correct? I checked the Cassandra release notes but couldn't find that version.

Assuming you mean 3.0 then you can install DSE 5.0 on your nodes without any need for schema migration since it'll be the same major release of Cassandra.

Install docs should all be covered here:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/install/installTOC.html

If however you don't want to go that route you could also standup a new DSE cluster and stream your data across using the sstableloader tool:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader.html

Of course it goes without saying you should always test first before doing anything in production!

Comment: Version info of Cassandra: [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.3 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]. Sorry I guess it's not 3.3.0 but just 3.3. So you're saying if the version of Cassandra I have is supported by DSE I could install DSE on top of my existing Cassandra cluster? Also I was looking into the sstableloader tool, and it seems pretty involved, if I'm not mistaken do you essentially have to re-write the schema in Java? The docs did not seem particularly instructive, are there any good tutorials out there?

Comment: Ok so Cassandra 3.0 is the _latest_ version supported in DSE at the moment (DSE5.0.x). sstableloader will just stream sstables from one cluster to another. You problem here is that if your version of cassandra is newer the sstableformat might not be backwardly compatible. You shouldn't need to write anything in java, you do need to create the schema in the target cluster but that is just a matter of using cqlsh.

Comment: The SSTableLoader doesn't prevent us from having down time though. We would have to prevent the database from being written to while we run the SSTableLoader, so that the new DSE cluster is up to date with the most recent data, because as soon as the SSTableLoader finishes streaming the data, the DSE cluster will be out of date. A possible solution to migrate over to the DSE cluster is to update the code to write to both databases and read from the Vanilla Cassandra cluster, and then we could run the SSTableLoader for the keyspace, would this work? Is this our only option?

Comment: Its not at all uncommon for the writes to be "forked" into an old cluster and new one while migration is taking place. You should also be able to run sstableloader too, any older writes will be superseded by new ones and keys merged during compaction as per normal. My main concern here is that you appear to be running a newer version of Cassandra that what is in DSE at the moment.